# How many blocks can securely be encrypted with XTS

Tags: aes, provable-security, modes-of-operation, nist, xts

I could not find in the [NIST recommendations on XTS](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38E/nist-sp-800-38E.pdf) how many blocks can securely be encrypted with XTS-AES.

Through the recommendations, I've found:

> The length of the data unit for any instance of an implementation of XTS-AES shall not exceed $2^{20}$ AES blocks.

The specification cited in NIST [The XTS-AES Tweakable Block Cipher](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/1619/email/pdf00086.pdf) states:

> The number of 128-bit blocks in the data unit shall not exceed $2^{128}-2$. The number of 128-bit blocks should not exceed $2^{20}$.

From what I understood, data units are sectors, so a sector can have at most $2^{128}-2$ blocks but you can only encrypt $2^{20}$ blocks which cannot be correct (it seems too little compared to a disk's capacity).

Comment: Where can you find that in the specs? I don't see it in the NIST requirements. I see the $2^{20}$ in there, but I've been looking in vain for $2^{128-2}$ or $2^{128}-2$ blocks.

Comment: Sorry, it was some other paper from the bibliography The XTS-AES Tweakable Block Cipher http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/1619/email/pdf00086.pdf

Comment: I'd guess that $2^{128}-2$ blocks is the logical limit and that $2^{20}$ blocks is the limit for practical security. I can see a mention of $2^{40}$ in appendix D of the IEEE P1619 standard giving a probability of an issue of $1/{2^{57}}$. It could well be that they were aiming for approx. $1/{2^{114}}$ instead. But that's just guessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From what I understood, data units are sectors, so a sector can have at most $2^{128}-2$ blocks but you can only encrypt $2^{20}$ blocks which cannot be correct (it seems too little compared to a disk's capacity).

The data unit is the sector, yes, but both of those quotes only talk about the length of a single data unit. The larger number in the latter reference ("shall not"), is an absolute bound, while the second ("should not") is a recommendation.

The recommendation from the second reference is that a sector should be no larger than $128 \cdot 2^{20}$ bits, i.e. 16 MiB. SP 800-38E makes this recommendation a requirement:

> The length of the data unit for any instance of an implementation of XTS-AES shall not exceed $2^{20}$ AES blocks. Note that Subclause 5.1 of Ref.[2] recommends this limit but does not require it.

(The ref above is to the IEEE standard based on the draft spec you linked.)

---

The total disk capacity encrypted can be much larger, since it consists of many sectors. For recommendations, you can see appendix D.4 of the second specification, where $2^{36}$ and $2^{40}$ (1 TiB and 16 TiB) AES blocks are mentioned.

Comment: I'm however still wondering how that $2^{20}$ was calculated.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, I think it's just for compatibility/interoperability, rather than calculated in any way: "an implementation of XTS-AES may further restrict the length of the data units for any key [...] Restrictions on the supported lengths of the key or the data units may affect interoperability with other implementations."